# How to duplicate such that it doubles the size of the list by repeating them in order at the end of the original list

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to duplicate this list given below, any suggestion for help would be lovely(down below is my output)

```
    public class k {
    private ListNode front;

    public k() {
        front = null;
    }

    public k(ListNode sentIn) {
        front = sentIn;
    }
    public void duplicate() {
        // ListNode head = front;
        ListNode temp = front;
        while (temp != null && temp.getNext() != null) {
            temp = temp.getNext();
        }
        ListNode head = front;
        while (head != null) {
            temp.setNext(new ListNode(head.getValue(), temp.getNext()));
            head = head.getNext();
        }
    }

    public class ListNode implements Linkable
{
    private Comparable listNodeValue;
    private ListNode nextListNode;

    public ListNode()
    {
        listNodeValue = null;
        nextListNode = null;
    }

    public ListNode(Comparable value, ListNode next)
    {
        listNodeValue=value;
        nextListNode=next;
    }

    public Comparable getValue()
    {
        return listNodeValue;
    }

    public ListNode getNext()
    {
       return nextListNode;
    }

    public void setValue(Comparable value)
    {
        listNodeValue = value;
    }

    public void setNext(Linkable next)
    {
        nextListNode = (ListNode)next;
    }
}
```

My output
Original: 1, 5, 3, 4, 7
After calling duplicate:

### 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 7, 4, 3, 5, 1

Intended output:
1,5,3,4,7,1,5,3,4,7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're modifying the list while you're navigating over it. So your loop will keep going further than you expect. i.e. at the start of the loop you have head as the first in the list and temp as the last. You then add a next to temp, so when head gets to be temp (which was the end of the list) it will have a next.

Also as you're adding temp.getNext() as the next in the new ListNode the order becomes reversed.

If you take a snapshot of the list size and just loop that many times it might work.

```
public void duplicate(ListNode front) {
    //ListNode head = front;
    ListNode temp = front;
    int size = 0;
    while (temp != null && temp.getNext() != null) {
        temp = temp.getNext();
        size++;
    }
    ListNode head = front;

    while (head != null && size-- >= 0) {
        temp.setNext(new ListNode(head.getValue(), null));
        temp = temp.getNext();
        head = head.getNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: OHHHH! that makes so much sense thank you so much mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Do `temp = temp.next` in your loop after you duplicate the node.

(There's no need to use `temp.getNext()` when creating each new node; the loop above it insures that this will be `null`.)

Comment: But temp is a ListNode type and it only method available in listNode is .getNext()

Comment: My point is that `temp.getNext()` will always return `null`.  (And `getNext` is *not* it's only method.)